# Facebook Send Dialog Link Issues

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're using the Javascript SDK with the FB.UI call like this:

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to: user_ids,
    name: 'Example.com',
    link: 'http://example.com',
    picture: 'http://domain.com/image.jpg'
  },
```

If we try with our base URL, the site works fine. When we add something to url like /about/link, it doesn't seem to work. However, it doesn't seem consistent because some work, some don't. We're attempting to put a User ID into the URL but it's not taking it.

Any ideas why some might not work?

This error back is just a 500 saying we're working on the problem.

Comment: Can you please let us know the exact urls?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it works now. It appears that FB checks if that link is valid and the path wasn't available on our production site before that.